# Parse exception in try catch block to assign a response code - 2xx, 4xx or 5xx

Tags: java, exception, response, http-response-codes

I have Jenkins plugin written in Java. I am capturing all the workflows of execution of plugin in a integer variable in three ways **0(2xx workflows), 1(4xx workflows), 2(5xx workflows)** and sending them to SignalFX for metrics. Since this is not an API and errors will be mainly caught in try catch workflow.
I wanted to ask how to read error codes from exception class and categorize them in 2xx, 4xx or 5xx. Are there some rules which I can follow by?

```
    try {
            Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            sendToSignalFX(0,data);    // 0 means successful state
        }
```

Some of the exceptions classes I will be using are -
`Exception, IOException, InterruptedException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException`

Comment: What do you mean, " read error codes from exception class"?  Please elaborate with a code example. Have you looked [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)?

Comment: Hello, updated to answer your question. I can only capture exception and assign a response code. Is there any categorization for that - exception to response code mapping? @OldProgrammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may have to add a method to identify the failure reason from e.getMessage() for one OR have a custom exception to help with your case.
Also if it’s an HTTP request-related exception (from the error response code mentioned in the question details) or something, you may want to add a custom exception, instead of throwing the original exception. In the custom exception, you can add a custom field to get errorCode from the response code.

```
// MyCustomException.java
public class MyCustomException extends Exception {

  String errorReason;
  int errorCode;
  
  public MyCustomException(Throwable throwable, String errorReason, int errorCode) {
    super(errorReason, throwable);
    this.errorReason = errorReason;
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
  }
}
```

And in your request handler code:

```
try {
  // otherCode which might cause IOException
  // ...
  Response response = myHttpRequest();
  if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
    // identify the error code and set corresponding errorCode to MyCustomException. errorCode
    int errorCode = 0;
// parse response.getStatusCode() or equivalent of the library and reassign the value of errorCode
    throw new MyCustomException(e, e.getMessage(), errorCode);
  }
  // ...
  // otherCode which might cause IOException
} catch (Exception | IOException e) {
  throw new MyCustomException(e, e.getMessage(), 0);
}
```